# How do I use XSLT to merge XML elements and then structure elements/attributes of the same name/type?

Tags: sql, xml, xslt

**Main issue**

I have an XML file which has multiple similar elements with slightly different information. So, lets say I have two elements with the same X attirbute, but different Y attributes. Here is an example:

```
<FILE>
  <ELEMENT>
    <ATTRIBUTEX>1</ATTRIBUTEX>
    <ATTRIBUTEY>A</ATTRIBUTEY>
  </ELEMENT>
  <ELEMENT>
    <ATTRIBUTEX>1</ATTRIBUTEX>
    <ATTRIBUTEY>B</ATTRIBUTEY>
  </ELEMENT>
</FILE>
```

What I want to do is--based on the fact that both elements have the same X attribute--merge them into a single element with one attribute X and multiple child elements (of the same type)--each of which contain each of the different attributes Y. So, for example, I want my file to end up like this:

```
<FILE>
  <ELEMENT>
    <ATTRIBUTEX>1</ATTRIBUTEX>
    <NEWELEMENT>
      <ATTRIBUTEY>A</ATTRIBUTEY>
    </NEWELEMENT>
    <NEWELEMENT>
      <ATTRIBUTEY>B</ATTRIBUTEY>
    </NEWELEMENT>
  </ELEMENT>
</FILE>
```

**Possible solution?**

One possible solution I can think of, but lack the knowledge to execute, is made up of two steps:

1. Firstly, I could merge all elements which contain the X attribute so that the information is, at the least, in one place. I don't know quite how to do this.
2. Secdonly, once this is done, this opens me up--in theory--to use my knowledge of XSLT to re-structure the element.

**Problem with the possible solution**

However, once all elements that containin the X attribute are merged together (**first step**), I will have a file in which there will be attributes with the same name (specifically, the Y attribute). Here is an example:

```
<FILE>
  <ELEMENT>
    <ATTRIBUTEX>1</ATTRIBUTEX>
    <ATTRIBUTEY>A</ATTRIBUTEY>
    <ATTRIBUTEY>B</ATTRIBUTEY>
  </ELEMENT>
</FILE>
```

What this means is that--at least with my knowledge--when I execute an XSLT file on the above XML (**second step**), it cannot distinguish between the two Y elements when sorting them into the two new child elements (`NEWELEMENT`).

So, let's say I execute the following XSLT on the above XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="FILE">
  <Record>
    <xsl:for-each select = "ELEMENT">
      <ELEMENT>
        <xsl:copy-of select="ATTRIBUTEX"/>
      
        <NEWELEMENT>
          <xsl:copy-of select="ATTRIBUTEY"/>
        </NEWELEMENT>
        
        <NEWELEMENT>
          <xsl:copy-of select="ATTRIBUTEY"/>
        </NEWELEMENT>

      </ELEMENT>
    </xsl:for-each> 
  </Record>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is this:

```
<Record>
    <ELEMENT>
        <ATTRIBUTEX>1</ATTRIBUTEX>
        <NEWELEMENT>
            <ATTRIBUTEY>A</ATTRIBUTEY>
            <ATTRIBUTEY>B</ATTRIBUTEY>
        </NEWELEMENT>
        <NEWELEMENT>
            <ATTRIBUTEY>A</ATTRIBUTEY>
            <ATTRIBUTEY>B</ATTRIBUTEY>
        </NEWELEMENT>
    </ELEMENT>
</Record>
```

As you can see, the XSLT has taken all and any `ATTRIBUTEY` elements and put them into each `NEWELEMENT` rather than distinguishing between them and placing one `ATTRIBUTEY` in the first `NEWELEMENT`, and the second `ATTRIBUTEY` in the second `NEWELEMENT`. I am in need of an XSLT file which does just that, and, as stated further up, produces an XML that looks like this:

```
<FILE>
  <ELEMENT>
    <ATTRIBUTEX>1</ATTRIBUTEX>
    <NEWELEMENT>
      <ATTRIBUTEY>A</ATTRIBUTEY>
    </NEWELEMENT>
    <NEWELEMENT>
      <ATTRIBUTEY>B</ATTRIBUTEY>
    </NEWELEMENT>
  </ELEMENT>
</FILE>
```

Would anyone be able to help me with this? Any solutions which generate the desired output (above) from the very first example file would be much appreciated! It's a bonus if that solution follows steps one and two. Thanks!

Comment: Probably xml tools of your DBMS could help. What is your DBMS?

Comment: That is grouping, you can find more details in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info and obviously any previous questions/answers on grouping.

Comment: The "problem" of processing each `ATTRIBUTEY` is solved easily by doing either `for-each` or `apply-templates` and selecting the current group. The exact method depends on the XSLT version that your processor supports.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting your requested output from the XSLT 3.0 below.

Just a couple of notes beforehand:

1. You mention ATTRIBUTEs but, in fact, everything is an element in your XML document.  There are no attributes in the XML sense.
2. I really don't see the need to create the additional subelements .. you can already have a list of elements of the same name.

Nonetheless, as an exercise in style(sheets), here is a stylesheet that produces your output from your given input:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/FILE" >
    <FILE>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="name(.)" >
        <xsl:variable name="parentName" as="xs:string" select="current-grouping-key()" /> 
        
        <xsl:variable name="childNamesSameValues" as="xs:string*" >
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/*" group-by="name(.)" >
            <xsl:if test="count(distinct-values(current-group()/text())) eq 1">
              <xsl:sequence select="current-grouping-key()" />
            </xsl:if>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:variable>
            
        <xsl:element name="{$parentName}" >
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/*" group-by="name(.)" >
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() = $childNamesSameValues">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()[1]" />
              </xsl:when>
              <xsl:otherwise >
                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()" >
                  <xsl:element name="NEW{$parentName}" >
                    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
                  </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </FILE>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I believe it could be a lot simpler. But I also suspect OP is limited to XSLT 1.0, so it probably doesn't matter. I just wouldn't want OP to feel discouraged.